# Difference between two timestamp with all elements of dates

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just wanted to subtract between two dates in Snowflake and get the output with all elements of dates.

For example:

I have two dates
2022-05-02 20:10:30.090
2021-04-01 10:05:20.080

And I want output as
10101100510010

Please let me know if there is any way of doing this in Snowflake.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question does not make any sense, but if this is what you want:

> I have two dates 2022-05-02 20:10:30.090 2021-04-01 10:05:20.080
>
> And I want output as 10101100510010

Here is the solution:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE( '2022-05-02 20:10:30.090', '[- :.]*', '')::NUMBER -
       REGEXP_REPLACE( '2021-04-01 10:05:20.080', '[- :.]*', '')::NUMBER as RESULT;
```

[image]

I would prefer something like this:

```
select timediff(milliseconds, '2021-04-01 10:05:20.080', '2022-05-02 20:10:30.090' );
```

Comment: I agree with you about the question doesn't make sense it should be easier using timediff, but I wonder if he just want the differences in 1 text without separation. in that case the differences should still use normal calculation, like time (hhmmss) means 201030 - 100540 should be 100450 instead of 100490, I dont really know about this because we cant see it from the example